# Export GPX from Wikidata geoshape

Tags: wikidata, gpx

Is there a way to export the geoshape from Wikidata to a GPX file? I would like to display certain geoshapes on my GPS device.

Here is an example geoshape:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data:/Sweden/Nature_reserves/2020/Glaskogen/2002147.map
- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1529632

Comment: Mediawiki Commons .map files appear to be a proprietary JSON format which wraps GeoJSON. If you strip off the outer wrapper, you should be able to feed the GeoJSON to a converter to get GPX files.